# django ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am getting this error whenever i started the server through `manage.py`, There is no error in my app or project , **I googled the error , but didn't get the satisfied answer,** Please tell me what is the reason for below error

> ```
> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
>
> GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 500 59
> ```

I am not getting this error every time, sometimes i am getting this error , sometimes not.

There is a huge stack of error out of i pasted only some lines of error which is the starting point for this error, Please tell how to avoid this type of error.

Comment: You you also run the server that is the target of this request? `500` indicates a server side problem, that has to be investigated and fixed there.

Comment: How to fix this? Please help me .